# Why is there a decreases in number of upvotes and increase in downvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, statistics, up-votes

[image]

$$\begin{align}&\left(\frac{du}{dt}\approx0\right)_{\text{Jul,2014}}&&,\text{$u=<$no.of up votes$>$}\\&\left(\frac{dd}{dt}\gg0\right)_{\text{Jul,2014}}&&,\text{$d=<$no.of down votes$>$}\end{align}$$
**Simply Why?**

P.S. Humour intended.

Comment: There is one confounding factor that might or might not be responsible for a large part of that increase. Posts with downvotes are much more likely to be deleted than posts without them, and SEDE doesn't contain information about deleted posts.

Comment: I think it would be good to include a link to the source of the graph. (Is it from some SEDE query?)

Comment: It appears the graph comes from [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#graph), which counts the number of votes (up and down) cast each month on _questions_ that are less than 31 days old at the time of the vote.

Comment: For comparison, [same data for Stack Overflow (with discussion)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270387/).

Comment: Maybe it is easier to downvote,and then go on to downvote the next question, than to answer.